# I have been trying to retrieve data from Firestore to Future builder of Flutter but on first build I get error message I get data after refreshing it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVNTS.png)[enter image description here][2]    Future _getName() async{
        return await Firestore.instance.collection("admin_details").document(_username).get();
      }

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                  future: _getName(),
                  builder: (context,snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        if (snapshot.data != null) {
                          return Text(snapshot.data['first_name']);
                        }
                        else {
                          return Text("Loading...");
                        }
                      }

                      else {
                        return Text("No Data");
                      }
                    }
                    else{
                      return null;
                    }
                  }
              ),
```

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#8f31b):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder file:///D:/Flutter/ecoleami1_0/lib/StudentActivity.dart:52:28
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

## 0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)

## 1      DocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:31:42)

## 2      _StudentActivityPageState.build. (package:ecoleami1_0/StudentActivity.dart:57:50)

## 3      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)

## 4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:27)

...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: i get data after hot reloading application

Comment: add your firestore to the question

Comment: Image added of my Firestore structure

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVNTS.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection("admin_details")
                .document('name of the document')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var username = snapshot.data;
                return Text(username['first_name']);
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Why ask him to use a streambuilder when he needs a futurebuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I’m on phone now, so am not 100% sure, but this might be, because your code returns null when the connection state is other than done so:

Replace the ‘return null’ line with return Text(‘loading’);

Comment: if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
             return Text(snapshot.data['first_name']);
         }
         else {
            return Text("Loading...");
          }
       }
       else {
          return Text("No Data");
       }
     }
     else{
       return Text("Loading");
      } i tried what you said but problem remains same getting same error and i get data after hot reloading.

Comment: Did you rebuild the app?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is caused by bad state management in the app..